# Smart way to use inheritance in JavaPoet

Tags: java, javapoet

I'm trying to build a class in this way (using the JavaPoet lib):

```
theClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder(classe.getName())
                                    .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(classe.getProte().toString().toUpperCase()), Modifier.FINAL) //todo
                                    .addMethods(methods)
                                    .superclass(father)
                                    .addFields(fields)
                                    .build();
```

Where the field "father" can be nothing. I tried using to put NULL inside it, but it gives an exception this way. Isn't there a smart way to write it?

I could write something like

```
if (father!=null){
   theClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder(classe.getName())
                                .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(classe.getProte().toString().toUpperCase()), Modifier.FINAL) //todo
                                .addMethods(methods)
                                .superclass(father)
                                .addFields(fields)
                                .build();
}
else{
   theClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder(classe.getName())
                                .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(classe.getProte().toString().toUpperCase()), Modifier.FINAL) //todo
                                .addMethods(methods)
                                .addFields(fields)
                                .build();
}
```

But that wouldn't be nice. Any advice?

Comment: Does a father == null ? Object.class : father work ?

Comment: *Smart* and *nice* meanings are not very clear in this context. Please add some details in what do you mean by them. For instance, _it wouldn't be nice_ **because it adds duplicate code**

Comment: muzzlator-> Almost right: (father==null?ClassName.OBJECT:father) but thank you very much!

@GonzaloMatheu Thanks! I will remember that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do immediately to shorten the code is to populate the builder with most of the fields you want first:

```
public TypeSpec aNiceMethod(
     ClassModel classe, TypeName father, ArrayList methods, ArrayList fields) {

   TypeSpec.Builder theClassBuilder = TypeSpec.classBuilder(classe.getName())
       .addModifiers(
           javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(
               classe.getProte().toString().toUpperCase()),
               Modifier.FINAL)
       .addMethods(methods)
       .addFields(fields);
   if (father != null) {
        theClassBuilder.superclass(father);
   }
   return theClassBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that wouldn't really work as you wrote it, yet the "inline if" you wrote as a comment was pretty useful. Thanks!

.superclass(father==null?ClassName.OBJECT:father)

Comment: Glad the comment helped. I'm confused though as to why you think this answer wouldn't work? I assume you're aware I switched `theClass` with `theClassBuilder` so you'd need to declare that variable, and I also used `return` to suggest that that's the object you want to end with

Comment: Yeah yeah, I just couldn't make it work because I was using the wrong Builder object. 
I proposed an edit, containing a Whole method instead of the previous code, thank you very much

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. Thanks for the edit, I removed some line wrapping too

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (father == null) {
  father = ClassName.OBJECT;
}
```

JavaPoet will do the right thing.

Comment: .superclass(father==null?ClassName.OBJECT:father) 
this is probably the best way, thank you very much!